# What does this recursive function mean?

Tags: mips

I've been tasked with implementing a recursive function in MIPS. This function is

function1(n) = n-5 (if n <= 3)

otherwise = 4*function1(n-1) - n*function1(n-3)

One of the test cases is if n = 6, then the result is 200.
How do you get 200 from entering 6 in this function? To me it looks like the answer should be 2. Is there something I am not understanding about recursion, or am I understanding the function wrong? I am so confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the function somewhere. Here are the steps I followed to arrive at 200:

```
function1(6) = 4*function1(5) - 6*function1(3)    (by rule 2)
function1(5) = 4*function1(4) - 5*function1(2)    (by rule 2)
function1(4) = 4*function1(3) - 4*function1(1)    (by rule 2)
function1(3) = 3-5 = -2    (by rule 1)
function1(2) = 2-5 = -3    (by rule 1)
function1(1) = 1-5 = -4    (by rule 1)
```

Substituting back...

```
function1(4) = 4*-2 - 4*-4 = -8 - -16 = 8
function1(5) = 4*8 - 5*-3  = 32 - -15 = 47
function1(6) = 4*47 - 6*-2 = 188 - -12 = 200
```

Comment: Thank for showing me. I've haven't seen a function like this with respect to MIPS and recursion, so wasn't quite sure how that all worked out

Comment: @ASchmalzWorld It's nothing to do with MIPS, it's just a mathematical function.